# Pull out data from each year in a dataframe and then use the matrix of data to calculate a statistic

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to loop through a large dataset with 41 years and pull out all data from each year and use it to calculate Moran's I spatial autocorrelation for each year. So in the end I would like to have 41 p-values (from Moran's I test) in a dataframe or vector so I can look at it.

Here is some example code:

```
moran.pvalue = NULL

#make dataframe- station, number, lat, long 
for(i in 1:length(unique(New.Data$Year))) {

mor <- New.Data %>%
  group_by(Trawl2, BegLat, BegLon) %>%
  filter(Year == New.Data$Year[i]) %>%
  summarise(number = sum(CPUE, na.rm = TRUE))

#make trawl row number 
rownames(mor) <- mor$Trawl2
mor$Trawl2 = NULL

#generate matrix of distances 
mor.dists <- as.matrix(dist(cbind(mor$BegLon, mor$BegLat)))

#take inverse of this matrix
mor.dists.inv <- 1/mor.dists
#replace diagonals with zero
diag(mor.dists.inv) <- 0

#calculate Moran's I 
moran <- Moran.I(mor$number, mor.dists.inv)

#pull out the p-value from the Moran's I calculation
moran.pvalue <- rbind(moran$p.value, moran.pvalue)

print(i)
}
```

So I am first subsetting the original data (New.Data) by year and then using this subset to reformat the matrix and calculate Moran's I.

When I run it now it gives me a vector of 41 values but they are all the same because I think it is running through the first 41 rows of New.Data instead of using all the data in each unique year to make the matrix that is used to calculate Moran's I.

Comment: Hi Haley, try doing for(i in unique(New.Data$Year))

Comment: and filter(Year == i)

Comment: @StupidWolf thank you so much! It worked!